# Simple Chrome extension won't display popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a simple chrome extension that is supposed to show me the time in a popup. I am using online resources from here and there to learn. Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Time Machine",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Get the right time, always!",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon19.png",
    "popup" : "popup.html"
  }
}
```

and **popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <style>
        body, html{
            height : 100%;
        }

        body{
            display : flex;
            display : -webkit-flex;
            flex-direction : row;
            -webkit-flex-direction : row;
            justify-content : center;
            align-items : center;
        }

        .maincontent{
            width : 100%;
            display : flex;
            display : -webkit-flex;
            flex-direction : row;
            -webkit-flex-direction : row;
            justify-content : center;
            align-items : center;
        }

    </style>
    <title>Time Machine</title>
    <body>
        <div class="maincontent">
            <p id="time"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var time = document.getElementById("time");
        window.onload = function(){
            time.innerHTML = Date();
        }

        setInterval(function(){ time.innerHTML = Date(); },1000);

    </script>
</html>
```

However, on clicking the icon after loading the unpacked chrome extension, **nothing happens**. I don't see the popup. **What is going wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 "popup" : "popup.html"
```

needs to be changed to

```
 "default_popup" : "popup.html"
```

Comment: Also, you need to move your javascript to a separate file and include it via a `<script src="xxx.js">` tag.

Comment: @rsanchez Yes, that, too :) Did that :)